# Test Harmony features with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

What would be the best way to test Harmony features with Jasmine? Jasmine doesn't currently run my tests as it is puzzled by the yields and * symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually run jasmine like this:

```
node --harmony ./node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node ./spec
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your tests in an environment that supports Harmony features. Check out the [ECMAScript 6 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for an overview of which features are supported in which browsers.

Even if your environment supports some of the new features, there's no guarantee that they conform to specifications. Make sure you read both the vendor documentation and the standard specification so you know what to expect.